# Google Sheets DATEDIF Function showing incorrect days

Tags: date, google-sheets, count, datediff, duration

I'm trying to calculate someone's age so that it displays the number of years, months, and days between their birthday and `today()` using this formula

```
=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")&" years "&DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"YM")&" months "&DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"MD")&" days"
```

I thought it was working fine until I noticed that date at the beginning of a month,

showed the same age as the date at the start of the next month:

[image: showed the same age as the date at the start of the next month]

It looks to me like Google uses a blanket 30 days when calculating `DATEDIF` and `"MD"`. Is there a way to fix or work around this?

[Here is a link to a test spreadsheet to work with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nrqY567EZhGk9rKtAmuIjNxm4LqMRshv5QK7xVzavGk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

nice find! I would call it a bug and report the issue to google via:

[image]

as this is ridiculous as their faulty documentation!

---

here is an alternative:

[image]

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(B, N, IF(ISDATE_STRICT(B), TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(LAMBDA(A, LAMBDA(X, IF(X<=0,,IF(X>1, X&A&"s", X&A)))
 ({DATEDIF(B, N, "Y")-IF((DAYS(N, B)<365), (IF(DAYS(N, B)<DAY(EOMONTH(N, -1)), 
 DAYS(N, B), IF(DAY(B)>1, DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))-DAY(B)+1, 0)+DAY(N)-1)>=
 DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))))-(((LAMBDA(Q, Q-QUOTIENT(Q, 12)*12)
 (COUNTUNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(N-B, 1, B), ))-2+
 (DAY(B)=1)+(DAY(N)=DAY(EOMONTH(N, )))))=11)*((IF(DAYS(N, B)<DAY(EOMONTH(N, -1)), 
 DAYS(N, B), IF(DAY(B)>1, DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))-DAY(B)+1, 0)+DAY(N)-1))>30)), 
 LAMBDA(Q, Q-QUOTIENT(Q, 12)*12)(COUNTUNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(N-B, 1, B), ))-2+
 (DAY(B)=1)+(DAY(N)=DAY(EOMONTH(N, )))), IF(DAYS(N, B)<DAY(EOMONTH(N, -1)), 
 DAYS(N, B), IF(DAY(B)>1, DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))-DAY(B)+1, 0)+DAY(N)-1)}))
 ({" year", " month", " day"}))),,9^9))), ))(B1, NOW()))
```

for array `B1:B100` it would be:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(B1:B100, LAMBDA(B, LAMBDA(B, N, 
 IF(ISDATE_STRICT(B), TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(LAMBDA(A, LAMBDA(X, IF(X<=0,,IF(X>1, X&A&"s", X&A)))
 ({DATEDIF(B, N, "Y")-IF((DAYS(N, B)<365), (IF(DAYS(N, B)<DAY(EOMONTH(N, -1)), 
 DAYS(N, B), IF(DAY(B)>1, DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))-DAY(B)+1, 0)+DAY(N)-1)>=
 DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))))-(((LAMBDA(Q, Q-QUOTIENT(Q, 12)*12)
 (COUNTUNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(N-B, 1, B), ))-2+
 (DAY(B)=1)+(DAY(N)=DAY(EOMONTH(N, )))))=11)*((IF(DAYS(N, B)<DAY(EOMONTH(N, -1)), 
 DAYS(N, B), IF(DAY(B)>1, DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))-DAY(B)+1, 0)+DAY(N)-1))>30)), 
 LAMBDA(Q, Q-QUOTIENT(Q, 12)*12)(COUNTUNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(N-B, 1, B), ))-2+
 (DAY(B)=1)+(DAY(N)=DAY(EOMONTH(N, )))), IF(DAYS(N, B)<DAY(EOMONTH(N, -1)), 
 DAYS(N, B), IF(DAY(B)>1, DAY(EOMONTH(B, ))-DAY(B)+1, 0)+DAY(N)-1)}))
 ({" year", " month", " day"}))),,9^9))), ))(B, NOW()))))
```

---

ofc, this will work only up to a particular moment in history...

see: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/74006429/5632629**

otherwise, this works even with leap years

---

also, note this feature...

[image]

how can be something old 36 days when the smallest unit of the month is 28 days and the largest unit of the month is only 31 days?

[image]

as it would not be fair / accurate to transfer Sep days into Dec nor Dec days into Sep to fill out the month as it would create multiple correct results:

- 3 months 5 days if Sep days transferred to Dec
- 3 months 6 days if Dec days transferred to Sep

Comment: Looks like that fixed one issue but created another. Looking at dates that are one year old, show it to be 1 year and 5 days, a 2 year old is showing 2 years 10 days, etc...